# Why time derivative of random process always zero?

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

It seems that whenever I am applying Ito's Lemma and am doing the time derivative bit it always turns out $$\frac{d}{dt}V=0$$
Take an example from a book
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{B^{2}}{2}\right) = 0$$
I don't get it, simple Brownian motion is a function of time:
$$B(t) = B(t-1) + Z \sqrt{t}$$
so how is this possible? Are we just pretending there is nothing beyond B in this composition?

Comment: Your equation for Brownian motion is actually an equation for a *discretization* of Brownian motion over time and it is slightly incorrect since $B(t)-B(t-1)$ is equal in distribution to a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ RV since $t-(t-1)=1$. More generally, $B(t_i)=B(t_{i-1})+\sqrt{t_i-t_{i-1}}Z_i$ where the $t_i$ form a partition of some time interval and $Z_i$ are IID standard normals. Anyway, BM is nowhere differentiable almost surely and has continuous sample paths, two facts well documented in the literature. $dB_t/dt$ does not exist in the classical sense of derivative.

Comment: (In the first comment the equality for $B(t_i)$ is an equality in distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Actually in Ito's Lemma you first recognize the expression as a function of $(x, t)$ and you differentiate the arguments accordingly, and then substitute the Brownian motion $W(t)$ back to the derivative by $x = W(t)$.

And although ordinary Brownian motion $W(t)$ has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, t)$ at every time point $t$, i.e. having the same distribution as $\sqrt{t}Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, they are very different in nature. The path of $W(t)$ is rough and no-where differentiable, whereas $\sqrt{t}Z$ is a nice parabola with a random coefficient $Z$

Comment: The first paragraph makes sense. Slightly confused about the second one. What is the point of $\frac{d}{dt}$ in Ito if stochastic processes are generally rough and nowhere differentiable?